# IF between two times powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out if an issue happened during a certain period of time however for what ever reason nothing seems to be working.

Here is my powershell.ps1 file

```bsh
$AUS_start = Get-Date -Hour 22 -Minute 00 -Second 00
$AUS_end = Get-Date -Hour 06 -Minute 00 -Second 00
$AS = $AUS_start.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
$AE = $AUS_end.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

foreach ($SHtime in $Rservices.start_time) {
    $x = $SHtime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    $x
    if ($x -gt $AS -and $x -lt $AE) {
        Write-Host "true"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "false"
    }
}
```

Here is the response I get

```
22:18:01
false
19:11:00
false
05:15:00
false
05:15:00
false
02:36:43
false
```

As you can see, there are certain times for example "22:18:01" that definitely meet the criteria of greater than UTC 22:00:00 and less than 06:00:00 but it still returns a false value.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is best to not convert times to strings. Is the intent to compare times, ignoring the date? Also, consider the date for 06:00:00 - the code doesn't include that.

Comment: You're converting the dates to strings - just leave them as date time objects and the comparison should work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton correct sir! how would I go about converting them to strings - I have done a .GetType() on $x, $AE & $AS and they both show up as string system.object?

Comment: @auburg I need to compare them based on times not date

Comment: @AndrewMorton There is a date for hour 06:00:00

Comment: @AyushLal Then create a TimeSpan object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan?view=powershell-7

Comment: @AyushLal - you may find it simpler to test for NOT within the hours. your time span is checking 2200 to 0600 _of the same day_, so you could check for NOT in 0600-2200 by testing for `$Current.Hour -notin $End.Hour..$Star.Hour`.

Comment: thanks @Lee_Dailey did you also have a code example? there was an example earlier but its somehow been removed?

Comment: @AyushLal - i saw that Answer & commented on it. i suspect the reason it was removed was that it was testing 2200 thru 0600 _on the same day_. and that doesn't work quite as expected. [*grin*] i will try to post an Answer based on NOT in hours 6-22 later this morning.

Comment: @AyushLal - please take a look at the Answer i just posted. it seems to do what you need, but it uses a slightly different approach to the problem. hopefully it does the job. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does what i think you want. [*grin*]

instead of testing for `in 2200-0600` it tests for `NOT in 0600-2200`. that test is simpler since it gives one a continuous range that is *all in one day*. if you need to allow `2200-2259`, you can simply shift the `$EndHour` to `21`.

please note that this *explicitly* ignores the *date* and only uses the hour-of-day. if you need to look at the date, that will require some extra code. if i understand your intent, tho, that seems unlikely.

what the code does ...

- creates a set of datetime objects to work with
  when ready to work with real data, simply remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and replace it with a call to your data source.
- sets the start/end hours
- builds the excluded hours range
- iterates thru the collection of test datetime objects
- checks to see if the `.Hour` of the current object is in the `$ExcludedHours` range
- if yes, writes a warning to the screen to not disturb the "normal working hours" folks
- if NO, writes a msg that it is safe to do IT work while the office folks are all far away

here's the code ...

```
#region >>> create some date time items to test with
#    when ready to use real data, replace the entire "#region/#endregion" block with the real data source
$RServices = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'LastYearElevenP'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddYears(-1).AddHours(23)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'LastMonthElevenP'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddMonths(-1).AddHours(23)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'YesterdayElevenP'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(23)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'ZeroA'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'OneA'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(1)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'ThreeA'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(3)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'SixA'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(6)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'SevenA'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(7)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'NineA'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(9)
        },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'ElevenP'
        Start_Time = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(23)
        }
    )
#endregion >>> create some date time items to test with

$StartHour = 6
$EndHour = 22
$ExcludedHours = $StartHour..$EndHour

foreach ($RS_Item in $RServices)
    {
    if ($RS_Item.Start_Time.Hour -in $ExcludedHours)
        {
        Write-Warning ('    {0} is in the Excluded Hours ...' -f $RS_Item.Start_Time.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
        Write-Warning '        Do nothing disruptive at this time.'
        }
        else
        {
        '{0} is NOT in the excluded hour range.' -f $RS_Item.Start_Time.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        '    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.'
        }
    '=' * 30
    }
```

the screen output ...

```
2019-04-29 23:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
2020-03-29 23:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
2020-04-28 23:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
2020-04-29 00:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
2020-04-29 01:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
2020-04-29 03:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
WARNING:     2020-04-29 06:00:00 is in the Excluded Hours ...
WARNING:         Do nothing disruptive at this time.
==============================
WARNING:     2020-04-29 07:00:00 is in the Excluded Hours ...
WARNING:         Do nothing disruptive at this time.
==============================
WARNING:     2020-04-29 09:00:00 is in the Excluded Hours ...
WARNING:         Do nothing disruptive at this time.
==============================
2020-04-29 23:00:00 is NOT in the excluded hour range.
    Now is the time to do things that the office folks might complain about.
==============================
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Lee. Although from my API call using the .hour im getting the following hours: 14, 12, 11, 7. I have set my $start to 22 and $end to 6. but its still telling me that those hours are within 22:00 - 06:00... Any ideas?

Comment: DO NOT use 2200-0600. that is not a valid range. it also spans TWO DIFFERENT DAYS. [*grin*] use `0600-2200` and test for NOT IN that range. my code lets you do the "it is safely outside of the protected hours" on the `else` branch of the `if` test. please, use the logical and predictable "smaller thru larger" range as the test range. it makes life [and code] so very very very much simpler.

Comment: Omg of course how stupid of me! Thank you so much sir, you are a life saver!!

Comment: @AyushLal - you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]